# ADA & GTK => function Get_Text

Tags: linux, function, gtk, ada, graphical-programming

I want to create a Toplevel window and use this function in it .

There is no example anywhere...

Here the complete description in `/usr/share/ada/adainclude/gtkada/gtk-gentry.ads`

```
function Get_Text (The_Entry : access Gtk_Entry_Record) return UTF8_String;
   --  Modify the text in the entry.
   --  The text is cut at the maximum length that was set when the entry was
   --  created.
   --  The text replaces the current contents.
```

For Debian and relatives OS , you can access to the directory after :    `sudo apt-get install libgtkada2.24.1-dev`

Comment: That function is for GtkEntry, a class that represents a widget that holds a single line of text that the user can type in. You will need to host that in a toplevel, and the class for toplevels is called GtkWindow. Note that these are the primary names for the GTK+ classes; the Ada bindings seem to use a different convention. I do not know of any good Ada-specific tutorials for GTK+, but Googling does seem to point to a few of them.

Comment: your answer is too general , i know how the widgets works with the library but you really not helping me here.....
Try to use the function and you will understand my problem .

Comment: The "testgtk" source is full of examples, and there are lots more in the distribution. Unless they have all been deleted with gtkada 3.x...

Comment: @infinite in that case I'm not sure what your problem is. How are you using the function, what do you get, and what do you expect? Once I know that I can try to reproduce the issue myself and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @BrianDrummond it seems to still be present at https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada/tree/master/testgtk

Comment: @andlabs =>I just don't know how to use this function , all i want is use this function as she is described in the package ( see my original post ) . Beside , i had search in testgtk and there is no example about it .

Comment: This question really has no context. We have no idea what was tried and what did not work. Obviously, to use the function you would need a Gtk_Entry widget, but I assume this is not the real question...

Comment: @infinite: Dude. You need to learn to use this site. You do not post Answers with modified code of the question. You just edit and update the question!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to use the Get_text function with the Entry .

manuBriot & andlabs =

I also found the Signal in the Entry's package for the reaction when the user press _Enter .

Finally , everything works fine now .

What my program do ?
= Its a window , look exactly like this :  http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1450777307.png

And , after you write something and press _Enter in the graphical entry , the result is print in command_line .

Simple and useful for begining in GTK language .

```
WITH Gtk.Main ;          USE Gtk.Main ;
WITH Gtk.Window ;        USE Gtk.Window ;
WITH Gtk.Enums ;         USE Gtk.Enums ;
WITH Gtk.Button ;        USE Gtk.Button ;
WITH Gtk.Alignment ;     USE Gtk.Alignment ;
WITH Gtk.Box ;           USE Gtk.Box ;
WITH Gtk.Gentry;         USE Gtk.Gentry;
WITH Ada.text_io;        USE Ada.text_io;
WITH Gtk.Widget ;        USE Gtk.Widget ; 
with Gtk.Handlers;

PROCEDURE prototype IS

-----------------------
   -- VARIABLES --    | 
----------------------------------------------------------
   win : Gtk_window ;

   Btn1, Btn2 ,Btn3  : Gtk_Button ;

   alignG, alignM ,alignD  : Gtk_Alignment ;

   Boite  : Gtk_VBox ;

   Boutons :  Gtk_HBox ;

   saisie : Gtk_Entry ;



----------------------------------------------------------
--Instanciation package(s) for connexion
----------------------------------------------------------

   PACKAGE P_Callback IS NEW Gtk.Handlers.Callback(Gtk_Widget_Record);

   USE P_Callback ; 

----------------------------------------------------------
--  Handlers (or callbacks)   |
----------------------------------------------------------

   procedure Stop_Program(Emetteur : access Gtk_Widget_Record'class)
   is

      PRAGMA Unreferenced (Emetteur);

   begin

      Main_Quit;

   end Stop_Program ;


   procedure Handler_text(Ent : access Gtk_Widget_Record'class)
   is begin

   put_line(get_text(saisie));

   end Handler_text ;

-------------------------------------------------
BEGIN

   Init ; 

----------------
   -- NEW --   |
-------------------------------------------------

   Gtk_New(win);   

   Gtk_New(saisie);

   Gtk_New(Btn1, "Bouton 1") ; 
   Gtk_New(Btn2, "Bouton 2") ; 
   Gtk_New(Btn3, "Bouton 3") ; 

   Gtk_New(alignG,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
   Gtk_New(alignM,0.5,1.0,1.0,1.0);
   Gtk_New(alignD,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

  Gtk_New_VBox
  (Boite, homogeneous => false, Spacing => 0) ;

  Gtk_New_HBox
  (Boutons, homogeneous => false, Spacing => 0) ;

---------------------------------
--  Add                    |
---------------------------------

   alignG.add(Btn1) ;
   alignM.add(Btn2) ;
   alignD.add(Btn3) ;

   win.Add(Boite);

------------------------------------------
--  Connect                   |
------------------------------------------

Connect(Widget => win ,
          Name => "destroy" ,
            Cb => Stop_Program'access);         

Connect(Widget => saisie ,
          Name => "activate" ,
            Cb =>  Handler_text'access);

------------------------------------------
--  Design Window          |
------------------------------------------

   Boite.Pack_Start(saisie);
   Boite.Pack_Start(Boutons);
   Boutons.Pack_Start(alignG);
   Boutons.Pack_Start(alignM);
   Boutons.Pack_Start(alignD);


   win.Set_Default_Size(500,500) ;   

   win.set_position(Win_Pos_Mouse) ; 

   -- win.set_opacity(0.7) ;

   win.Show_all ; 
   Main ; 

END prototype ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Gtk.Main ;          USE Gtk.Main ;
WITH Gtk.Window ;        USE Gtk.Window ;
WITH Gtk.Gentry;         USE Gtk.Gentry;
WITH Gtk.Box ;           USE Gtk.Box ;
WITH Gtk.Enums ;         USE Gtk.Enums ;

Procedure gtkada_get_a_entry is

    win : Gtk_window ;

   space : Gtk_Entry ;

   the_box : Gtk_VBox ;

      --    function Get_Text (The_Entry : access Gtk_Entry_Record) return UTF8_String;
      --    How to use the function ???

begin

 Init ; 

 Gtk_New(win); 

 Gtk_New(space);

 Gtk_New_VBox
  (the_box, homogeneous => false, Spacing => 0) ;


 the_box.Pack_Start(space);

 win.Add(the_box);

 win.Set_Default_Size(300,200) ;   

 win.set_position(Win_Pos_Center) ; 

 win.Show_all ; 

   Main ; 

end gtkada_get_a_entry;
```

All I want to do is use the `Get_text` function as it is described in the package.

The code I posted is minimal: prints on screen the text entry, but again, it's useless if I cannot use the function.

Comment: This looks like a useful addition to the question, not an answer.

Comment: WHEN do you want to get the text? After the user types something? If so, you will need to connect to the Gtk_Entry's `changed` signal.

Comment: @ andlabs  = I want to get the text after the user pressed "Enter"

Comment: Then you can connect to the `editing-done` signal (inherited from the GtkCellEditable interface).